# php 7.2 and libcurl

Tags: ubuntu, curl, libcurl, php-curl

php 7.2 as i think use libcurl with version 4
but when I set this version of libcurl in my Ubuntu, some programs became not working and more than this, system try to delete these programs. They are at least: Viber, Joxi and so on, and a lot of libraries which not works if libcurl3 is not installed
But without libcurl4 my php7.2 can't work with php-curl

So what should I do to make work apps like Viber and php-curl on php7.2 togeter?

Here is some command output from console to see more visual what I mean:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu-extra libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libdouble-conversion1 libgif7 libice-dev libmcrypt4 libpthread-stubs0-dev libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5network5
  libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5script5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xml5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb-icccm4
  libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xkb1 libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxt-dev python-apt python-pycurl qml-module-qtquick2
  qt5-gtk-platformtheme qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin qttranslations5-l10n x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl4 php7.2-curl
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  joxi libcurl3 viber
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl4 php-curl php7.2-curl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 245 kB of archives.
After this operation, 433 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt install php-curl viber`  ?

Comment: it will as I wrote unitistall libcurl3 and many more packages and install libcurl4, after that viber will not install and work

Comment: after installing php-curl and libcurl4 with it viber says that:   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 viber : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not only with the viber.deb file but also with the libcurl3 requirement of viber.deb.

In Ubuntu 18.04 libcurl3 cannot coexist with libcurl4 so you are going to face problems with other applications. In my case Viber and Steam could not coexist.

After some search I found the following solution which is to deb-package, fix the dependency and then build a new viber file.

The steps are:

Save the viber.deb file in a folder
Open the folder in a terminal
execute the following commands

```
dpkg-deb -x viber.deb viber
dpkg-deb --control viber.deb viber/DEBIAN
```

Edit viber/DEBIAN/control and replace "libcurl3" with "libcurl4" (also delete the last blank line from the file or you will get an error afterwards)

```
dpkg -b viber viberlibcurl4.deb

sudo dpkg -i viberlibcurl4.deb
```

or install the .deb file with gdebi
Viber seems to work ok with libcurl4 atleast for me until now.

solution from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030479/ubuntu-18-04-unable-to-install-viber